# "Create Unit Test" option greyed out in Visual Studio Premium 2010

Tags: database, visual-studio, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

Unitll couple of days before, every thing was working and today "Create Unit Test" option in the Database schema view is greyed out. I have checked all the references and are in place properly. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 0):

There must be some issue with the sql file that you are using. Check the Error List for Warnings/Error. One of the most probable reason for this could be that you might have specified [Database].[Schema].[Object] in one of the store procedure. To solve this just use[Schema].[Object] instead of [Database].[Schema].[Object].
eg use

```
dbo.MyStoredProc instead of MyDatabase.dbo.MyStoredProc
```

Comment: Hi Saurabh, Thank you for your reply. The SP is just using the SChema.object and there is not error for the particular SP i want to use.